# Rails 4 Modifying Scaffold Output. Removing Test files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to follow the guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html. In section 5 Customizing Your Workflow, it discusses modifying this code within config/application.rb:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.orm             :active_record
  g.template_engine :erb
  g.test_framework  :test_unit, fixture: true
end
```

However, when I open this file, I do not see these lines!

My ruby version is 1.9.3p327, and my rails version is 4.0.0

Are these lines located in another file? Did I generate my application incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That used to be commented out by default in Rails 3, it was removed altogether in Rails 4.  I think you should be okay if you just add it in manually.

Ryan has a few words about that here: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3

Comment: OK, I think I figured out my error: I put the above lines within the "module". When I moved the lines to the class "Application" within the module, I received no errors. Everything is good.